# itextsharp importing msmincho font style

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, itext

I am new in itextsharp and am trying to read existing pdf file and when i encountered a font used not a preset in itextsharp like msmincho, i would register it to font factory but how come when i tried to import the msmincho font style and uses identity_h or identity_v as its encoding it returns an exception known as font fontloc\msmincho.ttc with identity_h is not recognize.

the pdf was able to use this font style though, would like to ask what font does msmincho derives?

this is for the diamond symbol (like the dot symbol found in the list format).

i tried itextsharps fontfamily.symbol but to no avail.

i wonder what font would have symbols used similarly in msmincho if i really cant use msmincho.ttc font.

what kind of encoding does identity_h and identity_v are anyway?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

never mind i just use seguisym.ttf

Comment: how do you close a post btw? im gonna close this post since i found the appropriate font file.

Comment: @user2381378 You can delete the post or mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this example](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter11/TTCExample.cs)? A true type collection contains more than one font, so you need to add an index to indicate which font from the collection you want. Once you've done that, the encoding `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` will work (try the example and you'll see).